# In Rails 3 in Action, why doesn't User have a has_many association with Projects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, has-many

I've been working my way through [Rails 3 In Action](http://manning.com/katz/) and one element is confusing me.

Why doesn't User have a has_many association declared with Projects? Project has_many Tickets. What is it about the relationship between User and Project that differs from the relationship between Project and Ticket?

I would post code, but I think this question will only make sense to someone who has worked through the book (and therefore has the code to refer to).

Comment: Why would the user need to have many projects? That would mean that a project needs to have `user_id` attribute defined for it.

Comment: Hi. What I'm trying to understand is why a Project has_many Tickets, but a User doesn't has_many projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A user never needs to have many projects, because the way that projects are shown to a user is through a scope on the `Project` model. If you wanted to have this association, then you will need to have a `user_id` attribute on the `Project` instances.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I think I understand the mechanics underlying these relationships, but what I'm trying to understand is the reason for the decision. Why choose to use scope to show a particular User their projects, but use a relationship to link a Project with its Tickets? Why not use a scope on Ticket as well?

Comment: I can see that using a scope allows for a dynamic association, but how is this preferable to a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship between User and Project (Allowing a User to have many Projects and a Project to have many Users)?

Comment: I don't understand the obsession of having this association. What benefits does it provide? Why is it useful at all to have this association? What am I not understanding with your question?

Comment: I am asking the question to understand the decision making process that led to you choosing to use a scope on Project rather than a has_and_belongs_to_many :projects on the user. When we need a list of a User's projects, why is it better that this is done using a scope on Project rather than through user.projects. The latter seems far clearer to me, so I can see there must be good reason to prefer scope. I'm just wondering why scope is preferable to an association in this case.

Comment: Ah, now I get it. We do it this way due to some prescience in knowing that we're going to have different types of permissions later down the line. If we had this type of association then it would be fine for the read permission, but we'd need to architect a separate way for the other permissions. I've done it this way so that there's just the one way of defining the different permissions for each object and for each user.